# How can I access from next_purchase dataset used in "Predict Next Purchase" demo of Compose-ML?

Tags: dataset, automl

In the Predict Next Purchase tutorial available here:
https://compose.alteryx.com/en/stable/examples/predict_next_purchase.html

the first line calls demo.next_purchase:

`from demo.next_purchase import load_sample`

How to install it? Or get the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The dataset is available in this repo:

https://github.com/alteryx/compose/blob/v0.5.0/docs/source/examples/demo/next_purchase/sample.csv